# Not able to start 2 tasks using Dockerfile CMD

Tags: dockerfile

I have a question about Dockerfile with CMD command.   I am trying to setup a server that needs to run 2 commands in the docker container at startup.  I am able to run either 1 or the other service just fine on their own but if I try to script it to run 2 services at the same time, it fails.  I have tried all sorts of variations of nohup, &, linux task backgrounding but I haven't been able to solve it.

Here is my project where I am trying to achieve this:
https://djangofan.github.io/mountebank-with-ui-node/

```
#entryPoint.sh
#!/bin/bash
nohup /bin/bash -c "http-server -p 80 /ui" &
nohup /bin/bash -c "mb --port 2525 --configfile /mb/imposters.ejs --allowInjection" &
jobs -l
```

Displays this output but the ports are not listening:

```
djangofan@MACPRO ~/workspace/mountebank-container (master)*$ ./run-container.sh 
f5c50afd848e46df93989fcc471b4c0c163d2f5ad845a889013d59d951170878
f5c50afd848e46df93989fcc471b4c0c163d2f5ad845a889013d59d951170878   djangofan/mountebank-example   "/bin/bash -c /scripts/entryPoint.sh"   Less than a second ago   Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:2525->2525/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4546->4546/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5555->5555/tcp, 2424/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2424->80/tcp   nervous_lalande
[1]-     5 Running                 nohup /bin/bash -c "http-server -p 80 /ui" &
[2]+     6 Running                 nohup /bin/bash -c "mb --port 2525 --configfile /mb/imposters.ejs --allowInjection" &
```

And here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8-alpine

ENV MOUNTEBANK_VERSION=1.14.0
RUN apk add --no-cache bash gawk sed grep bc coreutils
RUN npm install -g http-server
RUN npm install -g mountebank@${MOUNTEBANK_VERSION} --production
EXPOSE 2525 2424 4546 5555 9000
ADD imposters /mb/
ADD ui /ui/
ADD *.sh /scripts/

# these work when ran 1 or the other
#CMD ["http-server", "-p", "80", "/ui"]
#CMD ["mb", "--port", "2525", "--configfile", "/mb/imposters.ejs", "--allowInjection"]

# this doesnt yet work
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/scripts/entryPoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One process inside docker container has to run not in background mode, because docker container is running while main process inside it is running.

The `/scripts/entryPoint.sh` should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup /bin/bash -c "http-server -p 80 /ui" &
nohup /bin/bash -c "mb --port 2525 --configfile /mb/imposters.ejs --allowInjection"
```

Everything else is fine in your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Very much thanks to you.  Such a small thing to miss!