# Running kafka inside docker container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, dockerfile

I have download kafka version 1.1.0 and I try to add it to a container that have an image from java 8, my problem is with the docker file:

This is my docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8
WORKDIR /app
ADD kafka_2.11-1.1.0 /app
ENTRYPOINT exec bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties; exec bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

I try to run two commands, one that start zookeepeer and other that starts the broker but only the zookeeper is started, someone knows why?,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This entrypoint does not make any sense. It should point to a single script. Instead write custom script in which you would run two different processes, but this is discouraged, better run one container per process.

Comment: It should be helpful for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470044/not-able-to-start-2-tasks-using-dockerfile-cmd

Comment: Thanks for your help, so let me see if I understand, dockerfile can't run multiple commands only just one?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can define one script in `ENTRYPOINT` layer where one service is started in background mode and another one in the main mode. It exactly works for your case.

Comment: Neither Zookeeper or Kakfa will work unless you *configure them to communicate*. I suggest you use this instead. https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/docs/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to just start up a second container for Zookeeper.  The [official one](https://hub.docker.com/_/zookeeper/) works pretty well.

```
docker run --name zookeeper -p 2181:2181 -d zookeeper
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the kafka version I just download have zookeeper with it, Is there a version that doesn't have zookeeper? or I just use that version and ignore the zookeeper?, thanks

Comment: @AlanGaytan In a production Kafka environment, it's recommended not  to use embdedded Zookeeper. If you wanted to do this in a single container, there is one by spotify. https://github.com/spotify/docker-kafka

Comment: @cricket_007 yes you are right, is better to have both separated, I think the easy way is to use the official container from zookeeper, just I think that if I don't want to use the zookeeper that kafka provide, it will be better remove it from kafka but I don't know if exists a kafka version that doesn't have kafka

Comment: @Alan The Apache download of Kafka includes Zookeeper, only to minimize extra resources to download