# Run multiple shell scripts in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, shell, dockerfile

I have to execute a shell script `log-agent.sh` inside my docker container.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.authors="gurucharan.sharma@paytm.com"

# Install AWS CLI
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y awscli && \
    apt-get clean

VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
ARG PROFILE
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENV PROFILE_ENV=${PROFILE}
EXPOSE 8080
COPY entrypoint.sh /
COPY log-agent.sh /

# Set permissions for log-agent.sh
RUN chmod +x /log-agent.sh

# Use entrypoint.sh as the entry point
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

# Execute log-agent.sh
# RUN /bin/bash -c '/logs/log-agent.sh'
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/log-agent.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run your script
/bin/bash /log-agent.sh

# Checking for lead detection level
if [ -z "$LEAK_DETECTION_LEVEL" ]
then
  LEAK_DETECTION_LEVEL=advanced
fi

# Start the Spring Boot application
java -Dspring.profiles.active=${PROFILE_ENV} -XX:+UseG1GC -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=${LEAK_DETECTION_LEVEL} -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dloader.main=com.adtech.DemoApplication -jar app.jar
```

The application startup is successful, but the container is not executing the script. No errors in the logs as well.
Here is what I have already verified:

1. File location.
2. File permissions.
3. Validated the shell script for correctness. (proper shebang operator)
4. Script is executing correctly if executed manually from the container using the docker exec command

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can the agent run in background?

Comment: I recommend reading the [documentation on the `CMD` directive in dockerfiles (`docs.docker.io`)](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#cmd). The `CMD` is passed as argument to the `ENTRYPOINT` command if both are provided.

Comment: @JRichardsz Yes, it can and should.

Comment: What does `entrypoint.sh` look like? As @Turing85 has suggested, when you have an `ENTRYPOINT` script, that script is responsible for running your `CMD`.

Comment: @larsks Updated the entrypoint.sh file

Comment: Now I'm confused, because it looks like you're already calling `/log-agent.sh` in `entrypoint.sh` (and you're ignoring the arguments passed in by `CMD`). Why do you have both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD`? It looks like you could drop `ENTRYPOINT` and just use `CMD ["/entrypoint.sh"]`.

Comment: @larsks It worked by using CMD. Got what was being done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Why is not running?

Basically, is not usual to  use CMD and ENTRYPOINT **together**. If you do that, the cmd instructions are appended to the entrypoint as simple arguments. In your case something like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT["/entrypoint.sh", "/bin/bash", "-c", "/log-agent.sh"]
```

More details here

- [Docker entrypoint and cmd together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47648775/docker-entrypoint-and-cmd-together)

### Explanation

In docker, only one foreground process can run. Several processes in just one container is not a good practice.

[Docker official web says :](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)

> It is generally recommended that you separate areas of concern by using **one service per container**

Also to have several processes inside of one container is called: Fat container

Anyway you have these alternatives:

### #1 Supervisor

With supervisor, you can run several process in one container. For example: postgress + java. In your case, the supervisor config file could be like this

```
[program:java]
command=/entrypoint.sh
autorestart=false
autostart=true
process_name=java-app

[program:java]
command=/log-agent.sh
autorestart=false
autostart=true
process_name=agent
```

More details here:

[How to package several services in one docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70308825/how-to-package-several-services-in-one-docker-image/70326121#70326121)

### #2 Send agent to background

- First the java and agent launch should be in your entrypoint.sh
- The agent should be launched to the background before java

Something like this

```
#launch agent                   
bash /log-agent.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &

#launch java app
java -jar ....
```

- And your Dockerfile should end with `ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]`

Notes:

- I tried with nohup but it doesn't works with scripts inside a container: [Not able to start 2 tasks using Dockerfile CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470044/not-able-to-start-2-tasks-using-dockerfile-cmd)